# Developing of universal counter of objects

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I've been developing a class that will allow me to count separately objects of any classes I'll ever have. The class should meet the following demand: to be completely all-sufficient (I don't need to make changes to any class of objects being counted)

Below, here is a declaration of what I have now and it is what I aimed at:

```
template< typename T >
class Countable
{
public:
    // template< typename Type > friend size_t GetNumberOfObjects();
//private:
    static size_t GetNumberOfObjects();

protected:
    Countable();
    Countable( const Countable& );  
    ~Countable();

private:
    static size_t numberOfObjects;
};
```

We have the hierarchy of classes:

```
class Machine   {   };
class Tank: public Machine  {   };
class Plane: public Machine {   };
class Ship: public Machine  {   };
```

I can use class "Countable" the following way:

```
class Machine: public Countable< Machine >  {   };
class Tank: public Machine, public Countable< Tank >    {   };
class Plane: public Machine, public Countable< Plane >  {   };
class Ship: public Machine, public Countable< Ship >    {   };

int main()
{   
    Tank t;
    Ship s;
    Plane p;

    cout << Countable< Machine >::GetNumberOfObjects() << endl; // total number
    cout << Countable< Tank >::GetNumberOfObjects() << endl; // number of only tanks
    cout << Countable< Plane >::GetNumberOfObjects() << endl; // ...
    cout << Countable< Ship >::GetNumberOfObjects() << endl; // ...

    return 0;
}
```

But there is a problem: 
It's possible to access GetNumberOfObjects-method using class name: 
Machine::GetNumberOfObjects(). It looks like everything is a OK, but if I try to access the method using derived class name: Tank::GetNumberOfObjects() or Plain::GetNumberOfObjects(), it causes compilation problem.
It seems to be a little bit confusing for users.
And it's clear why it happens.

In order to avoid this I do the following: 
put the method into private-section and create an outer (friend) function. So there is the only way to access number of objects.

```
template< typename Type >  
size_t GetNumberOfObjects()
{
    return Countable<Type>:: GetNumberOfObjects();
}
```

The question is: are there any alternatives of implementation to provide the only way to get these counters without using such function?

Thinking of this I understood that it would be OK if users created derived classes using private inheritance from Countable-class instead of public. But I cannot make them do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, hope my English is readable =)

Comment: oh, the problem is caused because of Diamond inheretence.  Got it.  I had to read it a few times to figure out why it was "clear".

Comment: There's probably alternatives, but what you have is good, and I can't think of anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'd need to use virtual inheritance to break the ties of the ambiguous call to your `GetNumberOfObjects()` or alternatively, you can try using type erasure metaprogramming pattern and move the problematic function to the common base class.